# How to include a library module from another project's repo?

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, git-submodules

I tried to do the same by creating a submodule from `SmartGit` but it actually copies the full project; moreover I am not able to include it as I have to try using: `:old_project_name:common_lib` which doesn't work. Kindly read below for more details:

The new project's structure I want:
- lib 1 module
- lib 2 module
- ....
- application module 
- **common lib module** (I want this module from an existing project which has the same structure as this new project but the `common lib` is part of the old project itself)

Comment: Have you tried making the common lib a shared submodule?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep tried that but as soon I tried that it copied the full codebase which includes other modules and the app module for the old project as well  :s I thought that if I use submodules then I should only see a single empty folder (more or less) which directly points to the git repo for the common lib module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (application module)
   |__build.gradle
|__lib1 (lib 1)
   |__build.gradle
|__lib2 (library 2)
   |__build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' , ':lib1' , 'lib2'
include ':commonLib'
project(':commonLib').projectDir=new   File('pathLibrary')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib1')
    compile project(':lib2')
    compile project(':commonLib')
}
```

Pay attention to commonLib. You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, **not the root** of the project

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. What is the difference between this implementation and git's 'submodule` ? I have a doubt if this will work in case I make some changes in the common lib from within the new project so will they get pushed out to their respective repo too? without me switching to the common-lib repo itself? AFAIK submodule makes it a little bit more easier for this kind of scenario :D

Comment: You should be able to use submodule, using the path in the settings.gradle.

Comment: Can you please check my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094567/adding-git-repo-address-instead-of-local-path); it's in continuation to this one..thanks

Comment: nvm..I think I figured it out 'sir :D